# Invalid value with express validator using html and pug

Tags: html, node.js, express, pug, express-validator

I am new at pug and nodejs.
I am trying to create a validation form before i can send to the next page, but i am struggling with it. I have already succeed with form validation using html, but when i've changed to pug, i encountered issues and i get 'invalid input' with all the data i send.

here is the error:

{"errors":[{"msg":"Invalid value","param":"boardname","location":"body"},{"msg":"Invalid value","param":"ipaddress","location":"body"},{"msg":"Invalid value","param":"portnum","location":"body"}]}

Here is index form

```
<form action="/board" method="post" class="cntbox" enctype = multipart/form-data id="formBoard" name="formOfBoard" onsubmit="validateIndexForm(event)">
                    <!--Close Button of the pop up-->
                    <div class="righttopicon" onclick="closeForm()">
                        <img src="images/square-x.png" alt="close icon">
                    </div>

                    <!--Form with the necessary inputs (Name of the Board, IP Address, Port and upload file). All the inputs are required-->
                    <div class="col-100">
                        <h3>Add new board:</h3>
                    </div>
                    <!--Input for the boards name with max length of 50 characters-->
                            <div class="col-75">
                                <label for="bname">Name of the Board: *</label><br>
                                <input type="text" id="boardname" name="boardname" placeholder="Ex: Board 1" maxlength="75">
                            </div>
                            <!--Input for the IP Address that can only accept IP's and with a max length of 15 characters-->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-75">
                                    <label for="ipaddress">IP Address: *</label><br>
                                    <input type="text" name="ipaddress" id="ipaddress" placeholder="Ex: 192.168.1.1" maxlength="15">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--Input for the Port that can only accept numbers with a max length of 4-->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-75">
                                    <label for="portnum">Port: *</label><br>
                                    <input type="text" name="portnum" id="portnum" placeholder="Ex: 8080" maxlength="4" minlength="2">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--Input for the upload of the boards image that can only accept .png files-->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-75">
                                    <label for="imgadd">Upload image:</label><br>
                                    <img src="images/file-upload.png" alt="Insert image" class="insrtimg" name="imageboard" id="insertimage">
                                    <input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile" onchange="fileValidation(event)">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--'Save' and 'Discard' buttons -->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-80">
                                    <div class="btnformcontainer">
                                        <input type="submit" class="btnfrm btnconfrm" value="Save">
                                        <div class="btnfrm btndel"  onclick="discardValues()">Discard</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </form>
```

and the server (named servertest2 for test purposes)

```
var express= require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var {check, validationResult} = require('express-validator');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));


app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Allow to send json to the server
app.use(express.json());

//Serve images, css files and javascript files in the directory named 'public'
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//Load view engine
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, './public/views'));

app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/views/index.html'));
});

app.get('/index', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/views/index.html'));
})

app.get('/board', function(req,res){
    res.render('board.pug');
})

app.post('/board', [
    check('boardname').notEmpty().isLength({max : 75}),
    //check if ipaddress is an IP
    check('ipaddress').isIP() || check('ipaddress').equals('localhost' === 'localhost'),
    //check if port is a number with max length of 4
    check('portnum').isPort({max:4}),
], 
function(req,res){
    let errors = validationResult(req)
    //check for errors and return json with results
    if(!errors.isEmpty()){
        return res.status(422).json({errors: errors.array()})
    }
    console.log(req.body.boardname);
    console.log(req.body.ipaddress);
    console.log(req.body.portnum);
    //console.log(req.body.myFile);
    let nameboard = req.body.boardname;
    res.render(('board.pug'), {name : nameboard});
})

//Start Server
app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server listening at port 3000');
});
```

Comment: What was the data you put into the form?

Comment: text data on the first one, ip or 'localhost' on the second and max of 4 numbers on the third. Must ignore the file, because i'm still working on that. The validation on client-side is working fine

Comment: I've succeeded passing the data by using multer.

Comment: Where is the error occurring? In the validation or in the callback?

Comment: I have successfully found and resolved the problem last week, but thank you for the help. As soon as i removed the error after the checks on post request, i never had that problem again

Answer (score 0):

```
!= messages('message', locals)
    if errors
      each error, i in errors
        div(class='alert alert-danger') #{error.msg}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.